# Using Finite Difference for explicit discretization of conservation law system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to use finite difference to explicitly discretisize the following system:

$\frac{{\partial \rho }}{{\partial t}} =  - \frac{{\partial \rho }}{{\partial x}}u - \rho \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial x}}$

$\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} =  - u\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial x}} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left[ {\frac{1}{{\sqrt \rho  }}\frac{{{\partial ^2}(\sqrt \rho  )}}{{\partial {x^2}}}} \right]$

where:

$\rho (x,t)\,\,\,,\,\,\,u(x,t)$

But i'm having difficulties since the $\rho$ time derivative is dependent on $u$ as well! I don't know which time step of $u$ to insert (or vice-versa for the $u$ time derivative).

Can it be done with finite differences ?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes it can be done with finite differenes. A better way might be to use the [method of lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_lines) and use an inbuilt ODE solver like the Matlabs ODE45 solver to do the time integration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the methods of lines. Can you indicate how to use the finite differences here ?